# How i can get latest record by using FirstOrDefault() method

Tags: c#-4.0

Suppose i have 2 records in data base

1) 2007-12-10 10:35:31.000
2) 2008-12-10 10:35:31.000

FirstOrDefault() method will give me the first record match in sequence like 2007-12-10 10:35:31.000 but i need the latest one which is 2008-12-10 10:35:31.000

```
if ((from value in _names where value != null select value.ExpiryDate < now).Any())
            {
                return _names.FirstOrDefault();
            }
```

Comment: You need to sort first and get rid of the Any() call.

Comment: Your code in the if statement makes no sense. You select a collection of "true/false" elements. That code is equivalent with _names.Any()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
return _names.LastOrDefault();
```

However, your if just sends another unnecessary query (and it is a wrong query too). If you don't have any record, LastOrDefault and FirstOrDefault will return null. You can use something like this to improve the code:

```
var name = _names.LastOrDefault();
if(name != null)
{
    return name;
}

// other code here
```

If you really want to use FirstOrDefault, you should order descending, like:

```
var name = _names.Where(n => n.ExpiryDate < now).OrderByDescending(n => n.ExpiryDate).FirstOrDefault();
```